# Снова htaccess: перенапрвление с заменой в регулярном віражении

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Нужно сделать редирект с

```
/cars/Accord_2017/ на /Accord-2017
/cars/Civic_2017/ на /Civic-2017
```

Обращаю внимание на замену ВСЕХ знаков "_" на "-"

```
cars/([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)/?$ /$1
```

Шаблон написан, а как сделать в нем замену всех "_" на "-" ума не приложу

Answer (score 0):

```
/cars/([a-zA-Z]+)_([0-9]+)/?$ /$1-$2
```

Comment: сорри нужно заменить все  "_" на "-"

Comment: Сложно. Только если изначально заменить все "\_" на "-" рекурсивным mod_rewrite. На подобии: _RewriteRule ^([^\_]*)\\_+([^\_]*) $1\_$2 [N]_. И потом уже удалять _/cars/_. А может проще страницу с редиректом сделать?